# Multiple DOJO Data-grids not displaying in Accordian Containers

Tags: datagrid, dojo, tabs

I have a page with 3 tabs(**dijit.layout.TabContainer**) and each tab as 2-3 accordians(**dijit.layout.AccordionContainer**). From a single data store, I am trying to display different grids in each of the accordians.

I am able to display data in a single accordian, but the other grids show up blank, I cant even see headers. If I try to display multiple grids outside the tabs/accordians, it works fine. Not sure what is it that I am missing here.

```
        var jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ data:{
   "identifier": "rowIdentifier",
   "label": "gridIdentifier",
   "items": [
      {
        "rowIdentifier": 123,
        "gridIdentifier": "labor",
         "description": "Project Manager",
         "hours": 100.0,
         "rate": 100.0
      },
      {
      "rowIdentifier": 234,
       "gridIdentifier": "oem",
         "description": "Developer",             
         "hours": 100.0,
         "rate": 100.0
      }
   ]
} });               
            var grid1 = null;   
            var grid2 = null;
            var grid1Layout= [
                { field: "rowIdentifier", width: "auto", name: "Row Identifier",hidden:true },
                { field: "gridIdentifier", width: "auto", name: "Grid Identifier",hidden:true },
                { field: "description", width: "auto", name: "Tier/Description", editable:true },

                { field: "hours", width: "auto", name: "Hours" },
                { field: "rate", width: "auto", name: "Rate <br/>" }               
            ];

            grid1 = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                query: { gridIdentifier: 'labor' },
                store: jsonStore,
                singleClickEdit: true,
                structure: grid1Layout,
                rowsPerPage: 6
            }, 'grid1Node');  

            var grid2Layout= [
                { field: "rowIdentifier", width: "auto", name: "Row Identifier",hidden:true },
                { field: "gridIdentifier", width: "auto", name: "Grid Identifier",hidden:true },
                { field: "description", width: "auto", name: "Tier/Description", editable:true },
                { field: "hours", width: "auto", name: "Hours" },
                { field: "rate", width: "auto", name: "Rate <br/>" }

            ];

            grid2 = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                query: { gridIdentifier: 'oem' },
                store: jsonStore,
                singleClickEdit: true,
                structure: grid2Layout,
                rowsPerPage: 6
            }, 'grid2Node');


         // Call startup, in order to render the grid:
            grid1.startup();
            grid2.startup();
```

Below is my HTML

```
<div style="height: 105px;">
                            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width: 100%;"
                                doLayout="false">
                                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Labor" selected="true">
                                    <div id="LaborAccordian" style="width:auto; height: 300px">
                                        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" style="height: 300px;">
                                            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Tab1 Acc1" selected="true">
                                            <div id="grid1Node"></div></div>
                                            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Tab1 Acc2"><div id="SubContractorLaborGridNode"></div></div>
                                            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Tab1 Acc3"><div id="VendedLaborGridNode"></div></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="OEM products">
                                    <div id="OEMAccordian" style="width:auto; height: 300px">
                                        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" style="height: 300px;">
                                            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Tab2 Acc1"><div id="grid2Node"></div></div>
                                            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Tab2 Acc2" selected="true"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end of the div -->
                        </div>
```

I have all the appropriate DOJO.requires() in the . Please let me know what I am missing to display the same data store, in different flavors in different accordian containers?

Thanks
SK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, most likely the grid is created successfully, but doesn't show up because the dimension is 0 * 0. The could happen because when the grid is created in a hidden accordion pane, the size of the grid's containing DOM node is actually zero. So when the hidden accordion pane is made visible, the grid size is still zero. This also could happen due to dynamic height and width are specified in the grid's containing node using CSS, e.g. using height or width like `100%`.  Dynamic height or width may cause problem when calculating the actual height and width.

So my suggestion is to first check the DOM structure using Firebug to see whether the grid is created or not. Most likely you'll see the grid's DOM structure but it doesn't show up because the size is 0 * 0. You can use Firebug to verify it. If this is the case, you can manually instruct the grid to re-calculate its size again by using the `resize` function. You can use `dojo.connect` to connect to `dijit.layout.AccordionPane`'s `onSelected` function and invoke the grid's `resize` function. Then when a accordion page is selected, the grid inside of it is automatically resized.

Comment: I tried your approach the idea seemed correct, but it did not work using dojo.connect. Rather I used another approach given in an old post.
 `dojo.query('div[id^="GridNode_"]').forEach(function(node, index, arr) {
    dijit.byId(node.id).resize();
  }); `

[old post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127468/dojox-grid-datagrid-in-a-widget-only-renders-on-visible-tab)

Comment: Hmm, anyway, the basic idea is to call `resize` function to let the grid to re-calculate its size. I thought the `dojo.connect` should work because I did the same thing before in a tab pane of a tab container. Maybe the `dijit.layout.AccordionPane` is different.

Answer (score 0):

I think what Alex Cheng said is correct. And the following changes may slove the problem.

```
<div id="grid1Node" style="height:100%"></div>
<div id="grid2Node" style="height:100%"></div>
```

Applying heights for the container of the Grid dom node.

Comment: adding heights attribute did not help much but doing a resize() worked for me. Please see my response to Alex above. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use absolute (not dynamic) height settings, eg:

```
<div id="grid1Node" style="height:100px"></div>
<div id="grid2Node" style="height:100px"></div>
```